# Inserting into MySQL database using Prepared

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

I am using a `PreparedStatement` to `insert` into mysql,I get no error but data has not been inserted,when I check in the `mysql console` it says `Empty set`:

```
  public void insertGeometryValues(String gisuniqkey,String objkey,String objtype,String geometry)
{
    PreparedStatement statement=null;
    String sql="Insert into ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY, GEOMETRY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY) values(?,?,?,?);";
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement=(PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, gisuniqkey);
        statement.setString(2,geometry);
        statement.setString(3,objtype);
        statement.setString(4,objkey);
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also tried using a `Statement` like this and get this [ERROR](http://pastebin.com/MFGTp4zf)

```
 try {
        if(conn==null)
        {
            System.out.println("The connection was not initialized.");
            return false;
        }
        Statement st=(Statement) conn.createStatement();
        String sql="Insert into ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY, GEOMETRY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY) values('"+gisuniqkey+"','"+geometry+"','"+objtype+"',"+objkey+"');";
        System.out.println(sql);
        rc=st.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: In second variant you have some characters which corrupt your query.

Comment: the final single quotation mark in your sql string is the syntax error: " +objkey+"    **'**    );" or you need to add a ' before objKey if it's VARCHAR

Comment: 1) You never execute your first query, 2) your second query is susceptible to SQL injection, 3) casting to `PreparedStatement` shouldn't be necessary (unless you are trying to assign to something that is not `java.sql.PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `PreparedStatement` never actually executes the statement. Change your code to:

```
public void insertGeometryValues(String gisuniqkey,String objkey,String objtype,String geometry) {
    String sql="Insert into ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY, GEOMETRY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY) values(?,?,?,?);";
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        statement.setString(1, gisuniqkey);
        statement.setString(2,geometry);
        statement.setString(3,objtype);
        statement.setString(4,objkey);
        statement.executeUpdate(); // <---- This is what is missing!
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have also included try-with-resources so that the statement is actually correctly closed.

Answer (score 0):

the answer given by Mark is correct. that should help you inserting using prepared statement.

You Sql query for inserting using Statement is incorrect. you have missed the starting ' for objkey variable. the correct query is

```
 String sql="Insert into ZMAPERP_GIS_DB (GISUNIQKEY, GEOMETRY,OBJTYPE,OBJKEY) values('"+gisuniqkey+"','"+geometry+"','"+objtype+"','"+objkey+"');";
```